# PHP encoding with DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, character-encoding

```
<tag>
Алекс М
</tag>
```

When I try to get the content of the following code using DOMDocument functions, it returns something like:

```
ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑ Ðœ
```

I've tried setting DOMDocument encoding to different values (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1), using mb_convert_encoding, iconv and utf8_encode but without success.

How can I get "Алекс М" instead of "ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑ Ðœ" ?

EDIT: The input is coming from a page loaded with curl. When I output the page content to my browser, the characters are displayed correctly (so I doubt the input is the problem).

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the document and important the content into it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = file_get_contents('your-xml-file.xml');
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($string));
// if you have not escaped entities use
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'html-entities', 'utf-8'); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($string);
```

Comment: I had this problem with a simple £ sign and this answer seems to have solved it. It should be noted that if you use html-entities on the string, then you won't be able to do loadXML, because XML will complain about unknown entities; you'll have to use loadHTML. However, I suspect there's a function that will convert them to entities like &#xAB; or whatever. Trouble is, this isn't really a good answer because it makes the text unreadable, but PHP is a bit notorious for encoding problems.

Comment: I would like to note, that you can add this line at the end when you get the resulting HTML:
`$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'utf-8', 'html-entities');`
Which converts some html entities back to their original values.

Comment: Just fyi - I tried this (hoping for it to be the fix! :)) and i'm sure it is... however, my client didn't have the mb_string module installed (DOH!) so I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220737/domdocument-and-html-entities which did the trick for me (the utf8-encode/decode response).

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem after using XPath to parse DomDocument, and after reading this

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32547

I solved it like this

```
// Workaround because PHP 5.2.x has encoding problems, when we 
// update to PHP 5.3 this line is not necesserry any more
$content = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />' . $content;

// Creating new DOM document and loading HTML content
$dom_document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom_document->substituteEntities = TRUE;
$dom_document->loadHTML($content);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I am maintaining a legacy server running PHP 5.2.6 and have been having this exact issue. This solved it.

Answer (score 6):

Add xml header to you tags - try this:

```
$a = new DOMDocument ();
$a->loadXml ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag>Алекс М</tag>');
print htmlspecialchars ($a->saveXml ());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing HTML body content, wrap it in a full HTML document.
For example, if your content is UTF-8, use this function and pass your HTML to it:

```php
function wrapHTMLContentInUTF8Container( string $content ): string {
    return <<<HTML
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="C">
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>$content</body>
        </html>
    HTML;
}
```

Use it like this:

```php
$dom->loadHTML(wrapHTMLContentInUTF8Container($yourHTML));
```

This way the parser knows it's UTF-8 since it's explicitly specified in the HTML document and it will know how to handle Unicode.