# Disable html entity encoding in PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

I cannot figure out how to stop DOMDocument from mangling these characters.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->substituteEntities = false;
$doc->loadHTML('<p>¯\(°_o)/¯</p>');
print_r($doc->saveHTML());

?>
```

Expected Output:
¯(°_o)/¯

Actual Output:
Â¯(Â°_o)/Â¯

http://codepad.org/W83eHSsT

Comment: Why would you want that gibberish in an HTML document?

Comment: Anyway, it's more likely that your editor/file transfer program/the fact that PHP code is not Unicode is "mangling" them, than it is that `DOMDocument` has any problem.

Comment: I found out the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142120/php-encoding-with-domdocument/2671410#2671410     Just use mb_convert_encoding($string, 'html-entities', 'utf-8');

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Comment: Well, [this works](http://codepad.org/6njYDcTj).

Answer (score 6):

I've found a hint in the comments of [DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251) documentation:

> (Comment from <mdmitry at gmail dot com> 21-Dec-2009 05:02: "You can also load HTML as UTF-8 using this simple hack:")

Just add `'<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'` before the HTML-input:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//$doc->substituteEntities = false;
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . '<p>¯\(°_o)/¯</p>');
print_r($doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried everything on that page already. http://codepad.org/Sr3d710Q

Comment: It does work for me. Using UTF-8 for PHP files–I've tested that. I don't know, what Codepad is doing internally, but they are returning entities…

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
```

in the top of the document takes care of tags.. for both saveXML and saveHTML.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP DOMDocument** will not convert characters to htmlentities if the HTML is properly loaded in UTF-8 and has the meta charset=utf-8 tag.

**The idea is to:**

- Properly detect the HTML source encoding and convert it in UTF-8
- Load the DOMDocument with the UTF-8 charset
- Add the `meta charset=utf-8` tag to the DOMDocument
- Do any stuff
- Remove the `meta charset=utf-8` tag from after saving the result.

**Here's a sample code:**

```
<?php
$htmlContent = file_get_contents('source.html');
$convertedContent = mb_convert_encoding($htmlContent, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($htmlContent));

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($convertedContent);

// Create the meta tag element
$metaTag = $dom->createElement('meta');
$metaTag->setAttribute('http-equiv', 'Content-Type');
$metaTag->setAttribute('content', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Append the meta charset tag to the head element
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$head->appendChild($metaTag);

// Do any stuff here

// save the content without the meta charset tag
$new_content = str_replace('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">', '', $dom->saveHTML());

// save to a destination file
file_put_contents('dest.html', $new_content);
```