# HTML symbols in parsed XML

Tags: php, xml, regex, xpath, domdocument

Take this XML snippet:

```
<title>Foos&#146; bar</title>
```

When I'm parsing the full document with PHP's DOMDocument:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->saveHTML(); // Output: <title>Foos&#146; bar</title>
?>
```

I can see everything as expected, HTML symbol in the title.

Then I want to extract the title text:

```
<?php
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue); // Output: Foos bar
?>
```

Even when I debug and inspect the `$xpath->query('//title')->item(0)` object I cannot see the HTML symbol there. I've tried to change the encoding, the XML version and parsing options but no luck.

Also, I'm not sure what's the rule for XML tag interpretation, but I have a hunch that the HMLT symbol is parsed out because it's a meaningful token. If I change the XML manually to:

```
<title><![CDATA[Foos&#146; bar]]></title>
```

then everything is perfect, I can access my HTML symbol in the final result. Unfortunately in this case I don't have control over the XML source.

Do you have any idea? Other than using regex to replace the symbols before parsing it?

Comment: My guess is, that you’re out of luck with a codepoint, that’s named [“PRIVATE USE TWO”](http://codepoints.net/U+0092). The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) actively discourages their use.

Comment: You can check the length of the string. If it's 9 (instead of 8), then the character is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&#146;` is an invalid numeric character reference. You need to replace it.

However, good news is, you do not need to replace it all your own.

Those numeric entities pre-date a time in HTML/XML where the character set of which those numeric character reference were relating to, was not globally defined. Since HTML 4 and XML 1.0 this is the case, the code points of the Universal Character Set (UCS) of Unicode are used.

In case you've got such broken or older data, you can let [*Tidy*](http://php.net/book.tidy) do the clean-up work for you:

```
$xml = '<title>Foos&#146; bar</title>';

$config = [
    'input-xml'  => true,
    'output-xml' => true,
    'newline'    => 'LF',
];

$xml = tidy_parse_string($xml, $config);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadXML($xml);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<title>Foos&rsquo; bar</title>
```

The **Tidy** object also carries one warning then;

> Warning: replacing invalid numeric character reference 146

which is exactly why we used it.

If you want to learn more, the email listed [on this page](http://goodtools.net/pages/HowCharactersMap.html) might be interesting to you. This might also show you how to do it your own in case Tidy is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried utf8_decode?

```
<?php
$xml = "<title>Foos&#146; bar</title>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->saveHTML(); // Output: <title>Foos&#146; bar</title>
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$value = $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo utf8_decode($value); // Output: Foo's Bar
?>
```

More detail can be found at [at this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220737/domdocument-and-html-entities)

Comment: Thanks Marc, it made me realize that the character is actually there, but not renderable. Your example prints me out the unknown char (question mark) for some reason, but it's indeed something :)

Comment: @itarato, what if you set a different character set on your page, something like `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1')`.

Comment: I've tried with many variations, still getting the question mark :/ thanks anyways :)