# Problems with French encoding in DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath, domdocument

I try to parse a text in French from html element using DOMDocument and Xpath. The problem is that the output encoding is incorrect.

Here is a text in French:

```
à la téléchargez mêmes
```

What I see on output:

```
Ã  la tÃ©lÃ©chargez mÃªmes
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$html = '<div id="demo">à la téléchargez mêmes</div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);    
echo $xpath->query("//div[@id='demo']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Try looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142120/php-encoding-with-domdocument)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Thanks! It is working

Answer (score 3):

With this command:

```
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

you're commanding the **DOMDocument** to load your string `$html`

```
$html = '<div id="demo">à la téléchargez mêmes</div>';
```

with the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

But the string you use there was not viewed / typed by yourself in that ISO-8859-1 encoding but in the UTF-8 encoding.

So technically spoken, you've typed it wrong there ;)

Then on the other hand, when you command with your script to return a value:

```
$xpath->query("//div[@id='demo']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

[that value will be UTF-8 encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode) (scroll down to the *Notes* section and read about the character encoding).

To get a better view on the document, just output it directly after the call to `loadHTML` so that you can better see what is going on (`echo $doc->saveHTML();`, beautified):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="demo">
      &Atilde;&nbsp; la t&Atilde;&copy;l&Atilde;&copy;chargez m&Atilde;&ordf;mes
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, you've explicitly commanded to insert *Atile* and the *non-breaking-space* and all these other characters, the string was taken as HTML 4.0 and as the HTML in your string didn't come with any specific character encoding specified, [the default encoding (ISO-8859-1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-6.1) was used.

So for what you do there, you can further read on with existing material that covers this and has even more information:

- [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11309194/367456) (Jul 2012)
- [How to keep the Chinese or other foreign language as they are instead of converting them into codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10237238/367456) (Apr 2012)

And additionally to the [answer given in the first of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310258/367456) there is an additional way to do this in your case:

```
$saved = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$result = $doc->loadHTML('<?xml>' . $html);
                         ########

libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);

if ($result) {
    $doc->removeChild($doc->documentElement->previousSibling);
}
```

This example not only adds proper error handling and return-value check if the HTML could be actually loaded or not, it also prefixes you string with a magic-sequence "`<?xml>`" that will set `loadHTML` into UTF-8 mode. After loading the HTML string as with UTF-8 encoding, the **DOMProcessingInstruction** is removed again. The encoding will remain:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

echo $xpath->query("//div[@id='demo']")->item(0)->nodeValue;

# prints "à la téléchargez mêmes" now
```

Find it demonstrated online here across many differen PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/TT3SM