# UTF-8 with PHP DOMDocument loadHTML?

Tags: php, utf-8

Consider this example, `test.php`:

```
<?php
$mystr = "<p>Hello, με काचं  ça øy jeść</p>";
var_dump($mystr);
$domdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); //DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadHTML($mystr); // already here corrupt UTF-8?
var_dump($domdoc);
?>
```

If I run this with PHP 5.5.9 (cli), I get in terminal:

```
$ php test.php 
string(50) "<p>Hello, με काचं  ça øy jeść</p>"
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) {
  ["doctype"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
...
  ["actualEncoding"]=>
  NULL
  ["encoding"]=>
  NULL
  ["xmlEncoding"]=>
  NULL
...
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(70) "Hello, Î¼Îµ ï»¿à¤à¤¾à¤à¤  Ã§a Ã¸y jeÅÄ"
}
```

Clearly, the original string is correct as UTF-8, but the `textContent` of the DOMDocument is incorrectly encoded.

So, how can I get the content as correct UTF-8 in the DOMDocument?

Comment: I'm not sure if this string is really utf8 if you put the text in there like that

Comment: Thanks @aleksv - any suggestion what should I do to get the string to be utf8?

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142120/php-encoding-with-domdocument

Comment: Thanks, @aleksv - following that link I eventually found the hack http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251 which solves the problem...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) was built on [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) whose HTML parser was made for HTML 4 - the default encoding for which is ISO-8859-1. Unless it encounters an appropriate meta tag or XML declaration stating otherwise [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) will assume the content is ISO-8859-1.

Specifying the encoding when creating the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) as you have does not influence what the parser does - loading HTML (or XML) replaces both the xml version and encoding that you gave its constructor.

---

#### Workarounds:

First use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to translate anything above the ASCII range into its html entity equivalent.

```
$domdoc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($mystr, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Or hack in a meta tag or xml declaration specifying UTF-8.

```
$domdoc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />' . $mystr);
```

```
$domdoc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $mystr);
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulCrovella - I managed to get it working with the prepending xml declaration hack; posted my solution below... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post the OP code with the fixes that work for me:

```
<?php
$mystr = "<p>Hello, με ﻿काचं  ça øy jeść</p>";
var_dump($mystr);
$domdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); //DOMDocument();
$domdoc->substituteEntities = true; // no effect if hack is done
//~ $domdoc->actualEncoding = 'UTF-8'; // Cannot write property
$domdoc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // no effect
//~ $domdoc->xmlEncoding = 'UTF-8'; // Cannot write property
//~ $domdoc->loadHTML($mystr); // already here corrupt UTF-8?
//~ $domdoc->loadHTML(utf8_decode($mystr)); // this gets to <p>Hello, ?? ?????  ça øy je??</p>, so not all
//~ $domdoc->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($mystr, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($mystr)) ); // no dice
$domdoc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $mystr); // hack, http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251
// dirty fix
foreach ($domdoc->childNodes as $item)
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
        $domdoc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$domdoc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper (sets all three)
var_dump($domdoc);
print $domdoc->saveXML(); // without ->encoding = 'UTF-8': Hello, &#x3BC;&#x3B5; &#xFEFF;&#x915;&#x93E;&#x91A;&#x902; else OK
//~ print mb_convert_encoding($domdoc->saveXML(), 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'); // if without ->encoding = 'UTF-8', this is then OK: <p>Hello, με ﻿काचं  ça øy jeść</p>
?>
```

This outputs:

```
$ php test.php 
string(50) "<p>Hello, με ﻿काचं  ça øy jeść</p>"
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) {
  ["doctype"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
...
  ["actualEncoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["encoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["xmlEncoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
...
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(43) "Hello, με ﻿काचं  ça øy jeść"
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Hello, με ﻿काचं  ça øy jeść</p></body></html>
```

... which is all good now `:)`